# can we separate the main serialize method in different class to make it easier and less complex using boost libraries for c++?

Tags: c++, boost, encapsulation

how to separate the serialize method from this code and encapsulate it to a another class so that we don't have to write it in every class we create.

```
class Test  
{  
private:      
    friend class boost::serialization::access;  
   template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar,  
            const unsigned int version)   
    {  
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);  
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b);  
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(emp); 
    }  

    int a; 
    int b; 
    Employee *emp; 
public:  
    Test(int a, int b,int c, int d)  
    { 
         this->a = a; 
         this->b = b; 
        emp = new Employee(c,d); 
    }  
};
```

Comment: need to know quick..:(
have searched a lot...but not a single method is there whch i've found

Comment: If you want some non-intrusive serialization, make your data member public.

Comment: It can't be done. C++ has no reflection so boost can't know how many members your class has.

Comment: but then how they are able to serialize the STL libraries???
 @W.B.

Comment: @shivi each serialisable STL container has appropriate helper classes in `boost::serialization`. Those helper classes know about the internals of those containers / libraries. Now when you serialise, for example, `std::vector`, for it to be serialised you need to include `boost/serialization/vector.hpp`, which contains code that knows how to serialize a vector (by a means of defining `load`/`save` functions for vector) and you have to ensure that the contained type is either trivial or has appropriate `serialize` function defined.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#nonintrusiveversion) you can use a free function to serialize a class. Of course this requires the data members to be public.

For "real" classes that hide their data you could define a "serialization struct" that gets passed in and out of the real class for serialization purposes.

Comment: What do u means by "real" classes here buddy?? @Nobody

Comment: I mean classes that have private or protected data members. To access those you would need friendship and therefore have the serialization depencency creep back into the class. The solution I proposed is to create a transfer struct that holds all data which is needed for serialization and pass it in and out of the class and serialize this instead. Of course you still have to write all the serialization routines on your own as W.B. has mentioned in the comments.