# serializing classes using boost serialization without changing the class

Tags: c++, boost

this piece of code has to be written every time we make a class i.e.from `template<class archive>` to `ar` & `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b)` . How can we make it short?
and how can we serialize the stl containers  ?

```
 class Employee  
{ 
private:      
    friend class boost::serialization::access;  
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar,  
            const unsigned int version)   
    {  
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);  
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b);  
    }  

    int a; 
    int b; 

public:  
    Employee(int a, int b)  
    { 
         this->a = a; 
         this->b = b; 
    } 

};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [can we separate the main serialize method in different class to make it easier and less complex using boost libraries for c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603039/can-we-separate-the-main-serialize-method-in-different-class-to-make-it-easier-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start with the documentation :)

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html (start under **Serializable Concept**)

STL containers are serializable when you include the relevant header:

```
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
```

A host of other stuff is supported out of the box.

You *could* make generic wrappers for types that have already been made "reflectible" by other means (e.g. Fusion Sequences, Qt QObjects etc.)

Comment: this i know that we have header files to include in this but how they actually link between them i.e., they will obviously not alter the code in header for suppose std::vector.
so how they are actually creating the link between the boost serialization and the header for vector i.e boost/serialization/vector.hpp ???????

Comment: @shivi I have no clue what you want to know, that's not covered in the samples. You can - perhaps - find a more direct example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533863/boost-serialization-of-native-type-defined-with-typedef/22533995#22533995). Just including the header makes the OP's code compile

Comment: Mmm. maybe you want to know how `serialize()` knows that it's dealing with a vector? Well, that's simple overload resolution: `foo(int); template<typename...T> foo(std::vector<T...> const&);` will automatically call the right overload for `foo(42)` vs. `foo(my_vector)`