# boost serialization - with load and save method for single data type in different namespace

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

Below is example code wherein i'm trying to do serialization using boost.
For struct my_type serialize method is implementated but how do i serialize my_time and data_type as bcoz they are in different namespace

// MyData.hpp

```
namespace X { namespace Y {

struct my_type
{

      std::string a;
      double b;

   private:
      friend class boost::serialization::access;
      template<class Archive>
      void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
      {
         ar & a;
         ar & b;
      }

   public:
       my_type();
       my_type(const parameter_strings & parms);

       virtual ~my_type();

};


namespace Z
{
    typedef unsigned int my_time;
    typedef std::string data_type;
}


}
}
```

//MyData.cpp

```
#include <MyData.hpp>

my_type:: my_type()
{
}

my_type::~ my_type()
{
}

 my_type:: my_type(const parameter_strings & parms)
{   
    // implemetation
}
```

Since my_time and data_type are not inside any class or struct hence i don't how do serialize it.
what way i should serialize my_time and data_type in MyData.cpp file and if there is an it will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm. Just noticed you have received this comment before: [_"With respect to the actual typedef portion of your question, remember that typedefs are just syntactic sugar that makes the programmer's life easier. They're expanded to their actual types before the code is compiled. So a typedef is serializable if the underlying 'real' type is_. –  aruisdante Mar 20 at 13:12"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533863/boost-serialization-of-native-type-defined-with-typedef#comment34291601_22533863)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you have to do.

`my_time` and `data_type` are *aliases* for the types they are declared with.

Boost serialization has built-in support for `std::string` and `int` and won't see the difference.

Relevant information:

- [boost serialization of native type defined with typedef contained within struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22533863/boost-serialization-of-native-type-defined-with-typedef/22533995#22533995)
- [serializing classes using boost serialization without changing the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606857/serializing-classes-using-boost-serialization-without-changing-the-class/22607536#22607536)

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c39bfca8f79024dc)**:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>

namespace X { namespace Y {

    struct my_type {
        std::string a;
        double b;

    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
            ar & a;
            ar & b;
        }

    public:
        my_type(){}
        virtual ~my_type(){}
    };


    namespace Z
    {
        typedef unsigned int my_time;
        typedef std::string data_type;
    }

} }

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
    X::Y::my_type a;
    a.a = "in my_type";
    a.b = 3.14;
    X::Y::Z::my_time b = 42;
    X::Y::Z::data_type c = "hello world";

    oa << a << b << c;
}
```

Prints

```
22 serialization::archive 10 0 0 10 in my_type 3.1400000000000001 42 11 hello world
```